# What symbol should be used for the Michaelis constant?

Tags: kinetics, notation, enzymes

I have found two different abbreviations for the Michaelis constant: $K_\mathrm M$ with [capital subscript M](http://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~bs11/Lec/Lecture6.pdf), and $K_\mathrm m$ with [a regular m](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucbcdab/enzass/substrate.htm). Which form is better for use in an article to be published?

Comment: Whatever form that the editors want.

Comment: Many journals or scientific societies have a list of recommended abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In page 66 of the [2005 Green Book *("Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry")*](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf), IUPAC recommends that $K_\mathrm M$ be used as the symbol for the Michaelis constant. Note that $K$ should be italicised whereas $\mathrm{M}$ should not be italicised.

Thanks to Loong, who points out that the [ACS Style Guide (Chapter 10, p 186)](https://doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch010) actually suggests $K_\mathrm m$. The Style Guide, however, also states that it is "not intended to be exclusive; alternative choices, in many cases, are acceptable".